# How to synchronize threads in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

Considering the code below.

```java
public class Account {
    private static List<Double> log = new ArrayList<Double>();
    private double balance;

    public Account(){balance = 0.0;}

    public synchronized void deposit(double val){
        balance = balance + val;
        log.add(val);
    }

    public synchronized void withdraw(double val){
        balance = balance - val;
        log.add(val);
    }
}
```

Is the synchronization correct?

I would say yes, because the method that access the variable log are atomic (thanks to the word Synchronized).
I tested it in this way:

```java
Account a = new Account();
Thread t = new Thread(()->a.deposit(30));
Thread j = new Thread(()->a.withdraw(20));
t.start();
j.start();
sleep(300);
System.out.println(Account.getLog());
```

It seems to me that blocking is fine, as long as one thread is using the log variable, the other is not using it.

However, the text shows this solution (not explaining why)(-> stands for substitution):

```java
log.add(val)->
    synchronized(log)
    {
        log.add(val)
    }

log.add(-val)->
    synchronized(log)
    {
        log.add(-val)
    }
```

```java
class Account {
    private static List<Double> log = new ArrayList<Double>();
    private double balance;

    public Account() {
        balance = 0.0;
    }

    public synchronized void deposit(double val) {
        balance = balance + val;
        synchronized (log) {
            log.add(val)
        }
    }

    public synchronized void withdraw(double val) {
        balance = balance - val;
        synchronized (log) {
            log.add(-val);
        }
    }
}
```

Why should I lock the variable log? Is it not enough to synchronize the method?

Comment: Your `log` is `static`. It can be accessed by multiple `Account` instances, so locking on the instance itself is not sufficient. By the way, you're probably getting downvoted because you posted an image of code, instead of the code itself.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen But it's private, if I try to write a.log.add(30) it doesn't work, i can't access it without using the Synchronized method, what i am missing?

Comment: It's `private` to the class, not the instance. Multiple instances of the same class will access the same `log` property.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen thanks! I removed the image and updated the questions!

Comment: Rule of thumb: The scope and extent of a lock object should always be the same as the scope and extent of the data it protects. Your balance is an instance variable in the `Account` class, so therefore there should be one lock object per `Account` instance to protect it. Your `log` is `static`, so therefore, the lock that protects the log should be `static.`

Comment: @SolomonSlow Wow, that's usefull! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution code looks thread-safe to me:

- The `balance` variable for each account is updated while holding the account's mutex.
- The `log` is updated while holding the list's mutex.

One small quibble is that `log` should be `final`.  If anything was able to (for example accidentally) assign a new value to `log`,  different threads are not guaranteed to be seeing / updating the same list object.

However, your version of the code is NOT thread-safe.  It is not locking `log` while updating it.  That means that two threads updating different `Account` objects could simultaneously attempt to update the `log` list.  That could corrupt it.

---

There are various other things wrong with (both) solutions.  The most critical one is that you are using `double` to represent currency values.  That is a violation of normal accounting practice.  (And some bank customers will get antsy if you "steal" some of their pennies ... due to floating point rounding errors.)

Comment: I'm actually learning Java, so for now I'm avoiding every detail you mentioned. Just trying to understand the idea behind!

Comment: @LucaPedersoli that double for an amount screams "Future Problems"... express all the amounts in the smallest fraction of the used currency -  suggested decimals in Iso 4217 (es. cents for €). (In pratica esprimi gli importi in € in centesimi - moltiplicali x 100, e formattali "solo" quando li mostri a video (stando attento al separatore di decimali).

Comment: So the problem happens when I do something like this: **` Account a = new Account();
        Account b = new Account();
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> a.deposit(30));
        Thread x = new Thread(() -> b.deposit(70));
        t.start();
        x.start();`** because I'm trying to log with two Threads from two different Accounts, so they are not synchronized because I have only synchronized the same object! Right?

Comment: Right.  They are not synchronizing on the *shared* `List<Double>` object which they are both updating.

Comment: @StephenC Thanks, I finally get it! Thanks also for the other tips, which I will definitely apply!